# Convertir consulta sql a linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

tengo conceptos básicos de linq, pero me tranque con una consulta con group by alguien podría ayudarme a traducir esta consulta de sql a linq:

```
select at1,at2,count(1) 
from tabla 
where fecha=trunc(sysdate) 
group by at1,at2
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Para expresar `GROUP BY` de múltiples columnas y `COUNT` con LINQ:

sintaxis de query

```
from entidad in entidades
group entidad by new { entidad.Propiedad1, entidad.Propiedad2 } into grupo
select new { grupo.Key.Propiedad1, grupo.Key.Propiedad2, Count = grupo.Count() };
```

o sintaxis de lambda

```
entidades
    .GroupBy(entidad => new { entidad.Propiedad1, entidad.Propiedad2 })
    .Select(grupo => new { grupo.Key.Propiedad1, grupo.Key.Propiedad2, Total = grupo.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de lo que te ha contestado Equiso de forma muy correcta, también tienes que tener en cuenta que ese `fecha=trunc(sysdate)` , **en linq2Entities, se expresa mediante unos métodos staticos de la clase DbFunctions o EntitiyFunctions**, dentro del espacio de nombres **System.Data.Entity**, el primer es para la versión 6 de EF y el segundo para las anteriores. Así quedaría la cosa:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx
https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dbfuncions

```
using System.Data.Entitiy;

from entidad in entidades

where DbFunctions(entidad.fecha) == DbFunctions(DateTime.Today)

group entidad by new { entidad.Propiedad1, entidad.Propiedad2 } into grupo
select new { grupo.Key.Propiedad1, grupo.Key.Propiedad2, Count = grupo.Count() };
```